# Where does "printf"-output go if executable is autostarted?

Tags: pi-3, linux, lxde

I wrote a small C executable that uses "printf" statements for debugging, like

```
printf("Starting up...\n");
```

When I run the executable in a Terminal window with
**./myProgramme**
all the printf output appears in the Terminal window, fine so far.

But I want to **autostart** the executable and added the line

```
@./myProgramme
```

to the autostart file of lxsession (**.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart**)

After booting the Pi, the executable is running (I checked with ps -A), but I can't find the printf output anywhere I looked (/var/log/messages, /dev/stdout, /dev/stderr)

I also tried changing the autostart line to

```
@./myProgramme > /home/pi/myLog.txt
```

but no "myLog.txt" file is created after booting...

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some hours of trial & google I found my answer:

First, the **lxsession autostart** does not work like bash, so it ignores the "> /home/pi/myLog.txt" part of the line

When using **/etc/rc.local** to autostart myProgramme it kind of worked (it created the myLog.txt file), but the logfile contained no outputs from the printf commands.

I found the reason for that to be that my programme never terminates (it runs in an endless loop, monitoring in the background), so apparently in this case the "printf"-messages are only sent to stdout when the stdout-buffer is full (4K of text), even though all printf messages where terminated by a newline "\n". That's why I didn't see outputs in the myLog.txt file, at least not when I tested it, as the messages never accumulated to >4K size

After putting the line

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

into my C code and recompiling, the stdout buffer is disabled and now I see the printf-output in myLog.txt :-)